# How to get print on browser console using PHP

Tags: php, jquery, json

I am testing out my php code and want to make see the files that I am getting from json and check how it is displaying so I know how to send the code to mysql

php file

```
<?php

$json = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

 $obj = json_decode($json,true);
 print_r($json);
 print_r($obj);
 function debug_to_console( $data ) {
    $output = $data;
    if ( is_array( $output ) )
        $output = implode( ',', $output);

    echo "<script>console.log( 'Debug Objects: " . $output . "' );</script>";
}

debug_to_console( "Test" ); 

debug_to_console($obj);
 print_r("hello");
 echo "<script>console.log('" . json_encode($json) . "');</script>";
 echo "<script>console.log('" . $obj . "');</script>";
 echo "<script>console.log('" . '$obj' . "');</script>";
 var_dump('Hello');
 var_dump($obj);
 var_dump($json);
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8")


$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

 ?>
```

None of this prints to the console

Want code to print to the console

Comment: what does the html source look like (right click -> view source)?

Comment: why do you double-decode your incoming json string? I doubt this will work.. Make sure the rest of your code runs without stopping php/without throwing errors. The console.log part should work.

Comment: You can use debugger e.g. XDebug

Comment: @Jeff I updated the code and removed the double decode, I am still having trouble printing on the console. According to my network tab in the browser my json is successfully being sent to this php file and should be able to be printed on the console.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following function

```
function consoleLogs($data) {
    $html = "";
    $coll;
    if (is_array($data) || is_object($data)) {
        $coll = json_encode($data);
    } else {
        $coll = $data;
    }
    $html = "<script>console.log('PHP: ".$coll."');</script>";
    echo($html);
}
```

You can use this as :-

```
consoleLogs(array("test1", "test2"));
```

Comment: wouldn't it be better to log out the js object rather than the json string? (if it is an object/array)

Comment: @Jeff yes,  you can use this function for an array, object and simple string, it will work for all.

Comment: I'm not the OP, this was just a hint not to stringify the json at output

Comment: @RakeshJakhar did this work for you? I'm still not able to print on the console. Here is a live link . http://www.highdemanddesigns.com/arc3s/survey the function gets called after a user hits complete on the survey